# Is it Noetherian and can you find an ideal which is non-finitely generated in it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian

I have a lot of confusion in polynomial ring. Please help me explain it.
Firstly, as we know, if $R$ is a ring then $R$ is sub-ring of $R[X]$ and $R[X]$ is a sub-ring of $R[[X]]$. I just wanna ask that how about the ring $R[X_{1},X_{2},...]$ which is a sub-ring with the same operations of $R[[X_{1},X_{2},...]]$. Is it Noetherian and can you find an ideal which is non-finitely generated in it? I know that is easy like $(X_{1}-\alpha_{1},X_{2}-\alpha_{2},....)$. I do not know is it ok?
Moreover, denote it by $R_{\infty}$ then $R_{\infty}$ has a field of fractions, $L$ say. So why $L$ is Noetherian?

I see that if $D$ is a domain and $F$ is a field of fractions of it then $F$ is not $D$-module Noetherian. So is it contraction?

Comment: Why do you think you need to prove that $(X_1-a_1,X_2-a_2,\ldots)$ is an ideal?  The notation yields an ideal by definition (although it doesn't guarantee that it's a non-trivial ideal).  What's the point of trying to prove it's the kernel of some explicit ring homomorphism when it's already the kernel of the ideal quotient map?

Comment: That is just the definition of ideal, so I wanna to show the homomorphism which has it being a kernel. I know that is an ideal by what I definite it. Could you help me explain the last question?

Comment: For any ideal $I$ of $R$, the homomorphism which has it as a kernel is the quotient map $R \to R/I$.  It may be the case that this particular ideal is the kernel of a homomorphism from $R[X]$ to $R$ (as opposed to some other ring), but do you have some reason to fix it as such?

Comment: You want to show that $(X_1 - a_1, X_2 - a_2, \dots)$ is not finitely generated, right? Then why do you want to show that it is the kernel of a certain map? I do not see how this would help you. Instead you might just assume that a finite set of polynomials generate this ideal and obtain a contradiction from the fact that any element of $R[X_1, X_2 , \dots]$ already lies in some $R[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ (for some $n$). The field of fractions $F$ of a domain $D$ is a field and thus a Noetherian ring for the lack of nontrivial ideals even though $F$ might not be Noetherian as a $D$-module.

Comment: The first one I got it. But I do not know what you mean in the second one. The field of fraction of a domain D is not always Noetherian, right? It depend on that field has finitely generation or not. In this case, the fraction of domain $R[X_{1},...]$ is it Noetherian, it does not have finite generation?